"Anonymize" counts below 3 in gt tables
I am using RStudio.
The data that I am working with are not allowed to be published if any cells in a table contains a count of less than three (data protection causes). However, as you can see in the reprex below I get one count in underweight males without the disease.
GT table without "<3"
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)

df <- data.frame(
  disease = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
              "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"),
  sex = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male",
          "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female"),
  bmi_class = c("Underweight", "Underweight", "Underweight", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Underweight", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal",
                "Overweight", "Overweight", "Overweight", "Overweight", "Overweight", "Overweight", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", NA, NA, NA, "Overweight"))

df |> 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = disease,
    .tbl_fun = 
      ~ .x |> 
      tbl_summary(by = sex) |> 
      add_overall()
  ) 

df |> 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = disease,
    .tbl_fun = 
      ~ .x |> 
      tbl_summary(by = sex) |> 
      add_overall()
  ) |> 
  as_gt() |> 
  sub_values(
    columns = all_stat_cols(),
    pattern = "^1 \\(.*\\)$",
    replacement = "<3"
  ) |> 
  sub_values(
    columns = all_stat_cols(),
    pattern = "^2 \\(.*\\)$",
    replacement = "<3"
  )

GT table with "<3"
I managed to replace every cell value of 1 or 2 with "<3" using sub_values, however, the count can still be derived based on the proportions from the other levels and the missing data count together with the header count. Thus I need to also "anonymize" the proportions somehow and the missing data. Can you help me work this out? I have multiple variables, and in case the solution is to completely omit the missing data count, then I only want to do it in the bmi_class in the disease == "Yes" strata. The same goes for the proportions if they need to be omitted or altered (e.g. only include the levels with 3 or more counts in the proportion-calculation). An option could also be to change the NA to an interval, thus still keeping some information to get the sense of the magnitude of NA's.
I considered creating a new variable changing the count to an NA (and thus changing the proportions), however I am also using the stratified variable in tbl_uvregression, and I want that estimate to be calculated based on the true values.
My brain is at its limits now trying to solve this problem. Can some of you help me with other perspectives or even better: solutions?
Kind regards
Mathilde
Edit:
A simplified (no strata) example with two different versions of potential solutions.
New example

How would the publication of sample statistics compromise data protection - unless the tabulated properties are rare and specific enough to identify members of the (surely anonymized?) sample among the population?

The rules are unfortunately not negotiable. They are set by the data owner, and apply to all data regardless the specific situation…

if(   foo[j] < 3)  bar[j] <- NULL

Everything you're looking for should be possible. But it would be helpful if you could be more specific about exactly what you need. I suggest creating a mock of exactly what you'd like to see as the result. Also keep it simple and avoid the stratification for now.

@DanielD.Sjoberg One of the problems is, that I don't know exactly what I want. I find it hard to comply with the regulations and still present the data most transparent. So if you have any ideas, please share them.
I just updated the post with an image of a simplified table and two different solutions that might overcome the problem.
Thank you for reaching out to help me!

Here's a general format you could follow to change the way some statistics are shown in your table. In the example below, I only modified the n shown, but you could further extend this and change the function that formats the percentages.
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  disease = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
              "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"),
  sex = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male",
          "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female"),
  bmi_class = c("Underweight", "Underweight", "Underweight", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Underweight", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal",
                "Overweight", "Overweight", "Overweight", "Overweight", "Overweight", "Overweight", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", NA, NA, NA, "Overweight")) |> 
  slice(1:7)

# first build the table
tbl <- tbl_summary(df, include = c(sex, bmi_class), missing = "always")
as_kable(tbl)




Characteristic
N = 7




sex



Female
6 (86%)


Male
1 (14%)


Unknown
0


bmi_class



Normal
3 (43%)


Underweight
4 (57%)


Unknown
0





# extract the ARD, and change the default formatting function
ard <-
  gather_ard(tbl) |> 
  cards::bind_ard() |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    fmt_fn = 
      case_when(
        stat_name %in% "n" & stat %in% 0:2 ~ list(\(x) "<3"),
        stat_name %in% "N_miss" & !stat %in% 0:2 ~ list(\(x) ">2"),
        .default = fmt_fn
      )
  )

# recycle the ARD back through gtsummary
ard |> 
  tbl_ard_summary(missing = "always") |> 
  as_kable()




Characteristic
Overall




sex



Female
6 (86%)


Male
<3 (14%)


Unknown
0


bmi_class



Normal
3 (43%)


Underweight
4 (57%)


Unknown
0



Created on 2024-11-04 with reprex v2.1.1
